# QC via REST API

Tags: quality-center, rest

I'm trying to update defects in quality centre using their REST API from a curl-based script.

So far, I've managed to authenticate, store the cookie, and retrieve a defect's data from QC.

My problems start when I try to send data to update a defect, I always seem to get a 'method unsupported' exception.

My curl command is:

```
curl -b cookie.txt –T @xml.txt -H "Content-Type: application/xml; Accept: application/xml" http://qcserver/qcbin/rest/domains/DK/projects/R2/defects/74
```

I'm sending the following xml, just trying to update a standard field at the moment.

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?> <Entity Type="defect"><Fields><Field Name="owner"><Value>me</Value></Field></Fields></Entity>
```

The QC documentation says to use a 'PUT' command, so I've tried sending the XML using the -T curl option but that does not work, so I assume it still needs to be POSTed. Any suggestions gratefully received.

Comment: I'm more interested about the part which talks about authenticate, store the cookie, and retrieve a defect's data from QC.
Can you please explain how did you accomplish this?

Comment: 5 years on? Not really. You need the QC SDK though, the docs were useful IIRC.

Comment: Could you please share HPALM rest API details(URI, body, header) to create/update defects.

Comment: @krishnashah Considering this is almost a decade old, I think it's safe to say the original poster does not still have all of those details! :-O

Comment: @corsiKa I don't even live in the same country than when I needed those APIs! Ah, what memories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [curl man page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) says you need to use "-X PUT" to issue a PUT request.